# How can I copy records and all its related records from one database to another database using the index of the highest parent table?

Tags: sql, informix

The database that I'm using is Informix; the version is 9.4.

I have a scenario where I'm trying to migration some specific records from one database to another database. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do,

Let's say I have three tables A, B, C in database D1. I need to copy some records from these three tables to database D2.

The relations between A, B, C are here below,

- A - parent with primary key a1
- B - child to A with primary key b1 and the reference key a1
- C - child to B with primary key c1 and the reference key b1

I want to move some records from database D1 with a specific condition a1 = 'something'.  Along with A, I need to copy records from B and C that are related to A directly (A<->B) or indirectly (A<->C through B).

What is the easiest and most reliable way to copy the data?

FYI. This is a one time job, not a continuous one.

Comment: How big are the tables — how many rows to be transferred from each, and how wide is each row?  Are there any blobs — BYTE, TEXT, BLOB or CLOB — to complicate things (such as the size calculation)?

Comment: Note that Informix 9.40 has not been supported for a long time.  All of 10.00, 11.10 and 11.50, three of the successor versions, have also been out of support for a while, and 11.70 will be going out of support later this year.  The current version is 14.10; the prior version was 12.10.  Both of those are in support.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, if the volume of data to be transferred is small enough, then you could use:

```
BEGIN WORK;
INSERT INTO D2:A
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE a1 = 'something';
INSERT INTO D2:B
    SELECT B.* FROM B JOIN A ON B.a1 = A.a1
     WHERE A.a1 = 'something';
INSERT INTO D2:C
    SELECT C.*
      FROM C
      JOIN B ON C.b1 = B.b1
      JOIN A ON B.a1 = A.a1
     WHERE A.a1 = 'something';
COMMIT WORK;
```

It might be possible to simplify things if the condition on `A` is really as simple as `a1 = 'something'` so that there is only one record from `A` to transfer (since `a1` is the primary key of `A`).

```
BEGIN WORK;
INSERT INTO D2:A
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.a1 = 'something';
INSERT INTO D2:B SELECT B.* FROM B
     WHERE B.a1 = 'something';
INSERT INTO D2:C
    SELECT C.*
      FROM C
      JOIN B ON C.b1 = B.b1
     WHERE B.a1 = 'something';
COMMIT WORK;
```

This avoids joins back to table `A`.

If the volume of data makes this preposterous, you're probably stuck with something like unloading and reloading the data.  You'd be wise to lock the tables in share mode while unloading them.

What volume makes the triple-insert operation preposterous?  That's hard to answer, but if the transferred data requires more logical log space than you've got on the server running `D2`, then you've got problems.  Whether it is then best to split the transactions or whether to go for unload/reload is hard to decide.  On the whole, unload/reload is probably better if the space required is too large.